Memory leak in NodeJS (NestJS) when saving application logs
I have a server application written in NodeJS (NestJS). The application uses a tracer to store nested logs, and my problem is that creating an instance of the logger class leads to a memory leak.
The principle of operation:

A request arrives;
AsyncLocalStorage is created;
The request enters the Middleware (JaegerMiddleware), where an instance of the class (JGTracer) is created and stored in AsyncLocalStorage to be used throughout the request path.
In the services, the tracer() function from JaegerLoggerService is called, which in turn returns an instance (JGTracer) from AsyncLocalStorage or creates a new JGTracer if it couldn't find it in AsyncLocalStorage and saves it there.
In the service (example - ClientService), spans (startSpan function) are created and placed in a common JGSpan array to achieve nested logging.
In JaegerMiddleware, the 'finish' of the request is awaited, the logger is closed, and AsyncLocalStorage is cleared.

I suspect that the logger memory leak occurs because JGTracer stores JGSpan[], and each JGSpan stores a reference to JGTracer. I tried replacing them with null when closing, but it didn't help.
I would be very grateful if someone could help me find the problem in my code. Thank you in advance!
  ClientService
  async getList(getListDto: GetListDTO) {
    const tracer = this.jaegerLoggerService.tracer();
    const mainSpan = tracer.startSpan('ClientService || getList');
    try {
      const span = tracer.startSpan('getUsers');
      const responseUser = await this.userService.getUsers({...getListDto});
      span.finish()
    }catch (e){
      console.error(e);
      tracer.startSpan('Error').log({exception: {name: e.name, message: e.message, stack: e.stack}}).setTag('error', true).finish();
    }finally {
      mainSpan.finish();
    }
  }

JaegerLoggerService / JGTracer / JGSpan
@Injectable({scope: Scope.TRANSIENT})
export class JaegerLoggerService {
    constructor(private readonly als?: AsyncLocalStorage<any>) {}
    tracer(): JGTracer {
        if (this.als && this.als.getStore() !== undefined && this.als.getStore()['tracer']){
            return this.als.getStore()['tracer'] as JGTracer;
        }
        const newJGTracer = new JGTracer();
        if (this.als && this.als.getStore() !== undefined){
            let store = this.als.getStore();
            store['tracer'] = newJGTracer;
            this.als.run(store, () => {});
        }else{
            setTimeout(()=> {
                console.log('Tracer Close');
                newJGTracer.close();
            }, 20000);
        }

        return newJGTracer;
    }
}

@Injectable({scope: Scope.TRANSIENT})
export class JGTracer {
    private readonly agentHost: string = process.env.LOGGER_HOST;
    private readonly serviceName: string = process.env.LOGGER_SERVICE_NAME;
    public activeTracer: JaegerTracer = null;
    public activeSpans: JGSpan[] = [];

    constructor() {
        this.activeTracer = this.init();
    }

    private init(): JaegerTracer {
        return this.initTracer();
    }

    startSpan(name: string, options: SpanOptions = {}) : JGSpan {
        if (options.childOf === undefined && this.activeSpans.length > 0){
            options.childOf = this.activeSpans[this.activeSpans.length - 1].activeSpan;
        }
        const span = new JGSpan(name, options, this);
        this.activeSpans.push(span);
        return span;
    }

    finishSpan(jgSpan : JGSpan){
        const filteredActiveSpans = this.activeSpans.filter((span) => span !== jgSpan);
        this.activeSpans = filteredActiveSpans;
    }

    inject(span: JGSpan, format: string, carrier: any): void {
        this.activeTracer.inject(span.activeSpan, format, carrier);
    }

    close() {
        this.activeTracer.close();
        this.activeTracer = null;
    }

    private initTracer(){
        if (this.activeTracer !== null) {
            return this.activeTracer;
        }

        const newTracer =  initTracer(
            {
                serviceName: this.serviceName,
                sampler: {
                    type: 'const',
                    param: 1,
                },
                reporter: {
                    agentHost: this.agentHost,
                    logSpans: true,
                },
            },
            {}
        );
        this.activeTracer = newTracer;
        return newTracer;

    }
}

@Injectable({scope: Scope.TRANSIENT})
class JGSpan {
    private activeTracer : JGTracer = null;
    public activeSpan: Span = null;

    constructor(name: string, options: SpanOptions = {}, tracer : JGTracer) {
        const span = tracer.activeTracer.startSpan(name, options);
        this.activeTracer = tracer;
        this.activeSpan = span;
    }

    log(keyValuePairs: { [key: string]: any }, timestamp?: number){
        keyValuePairs = this.truncateLongStrings(keyValuePairs, 5000);
        this.activeSpan.log(keyValuePairs, timestamp);
        keyValuePairs = null;
        return this;
    }

    setTag(key: string, value: any){
        this.activeSpan.setTag(key, value);
        return this;
    }

    finish() {
        this.activeSpan.finish();
        this.activeTracer.finishSpan(this);
        this.activeSpan = null;
    }
    
    truncateLongStrings(obj, maxLength, depth = 0) {
        if (depth > 20) {
            return '{...}';
        }

        let newObj = {};
        for (let key in obj) {
            if (typeof obj[key] === 'string') {
                if (obj[key].length > maxLength) {
                    newObj[key] = '{...}';
                } else {
                    newObj[key] = obj[key];
                }
            } else if (typeof obj[key] === 'object') {
                newObj[key] = this.truncateLongStrings(obj[key], maxLength, depth + 1);
            } else {
                newObj[key] = obj[key];
            }
        }
        return newObj;
    }
}

JaegerMiddleware
@Injectable({scope: Scope.REQUEST})
export class JaegerMiddleware implements NestMiddleware {
    private tracer : JGTracer = null;
    constructor(
        private readonly jaegerLoggerService : JaegerLoggerService,
        private readonly als: AsyncLocalStorage<any>
    ) {
        this.tracer = this.jaegerLoggerService.tracer();
    }

    public use(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): void {
        let statusReq = true;
        const operationName = `${req.method} ${req.baseUrl}`;

        let mainSpan = this.tracer.startSpan(operationName);

        this.tracer.inject(mainSpan, FORMAT_HTTP_HEADERS, req.headers);
        const ips = req?.headers['x-forwarded-for'] as string;
        const userIp = typeof ips === "string" ? ips.split(",")[0] : 'null';

        mainSpan.setTag('http.client_ip', userIp);

        const token = req.headers?.authorization?.replace(/Bearer|\s/g, "");
        const dataToken = jwt.decode(token);
        if (dataToken !== null){
            mainSpan.setTag('employee_uid', dataToken?.employee_uid);
        }

        mainSpan.log({
            ip: userIp,
            headers: req.headers,
            query: req.query,
            body: req.body,
        })

        let store = this.als.getStore();
        store['tracer'] = this.tracer;
        this.als.run(store, () => {});

        res.on('finish', () => {
            try {
                mainSpan.finish();
                mainSpan = undefined;
                this.tracer.close();
                this.tracer = undefined;
            }catch (e) {
                console.error(e);
            } finally {
                store = null;
                this.als.enterWith(undefined);
            }
            statusReq = false;
        });

        next();
    }
}

I tried deleting the used variables, but it didn't have any effect.
